# Boolean Algebra Simplification Question (3 variables) What other Identities can I apply to simplify this problem?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

XYZ + XYZ~ + XY~Z + X~YZ  =  XY + XZ + YZ     || ( ~ = not notation)

Simplify the left side step by step

---

Here is what i have so far

- XYZ + XYZ~ + XY~Z + X~YZ
- XY(Z + Z~) + XY~Z + X~YZ   (Distributive)
- XY(1) + XY~Z + X~YZ    (Identity)
- XY + XY~Z + X~YZ

---

This is where i am stuck, I have tried distributing again and rearranging with the commutative property but i cant move forward. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some handy laws:

**Absorption**

$P + PQ = P$

**Reduction**

$P + P'Q = P + Q$

**Generalized Reduction**

$PR + P'QR = PR + QR$

Comment: what law is reduction?

Comment: @AhmedHanif That's the $P +P'Q=P+Q$ law, which can be proven by: $P+P'Q=(P+P')(P+Q)=1(P+Q)=P+Q$

Answer (score 0):

Using idempotent rule: $XYZ + XY\overline Z + X \overline YZ + \overline XYZ= XYZ + XY\overline Z + XYZ + X \overline YZ + XYZ+ \overline XYZ=...$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your last expression and applying the Generalized Reduction (Bram28's answer) we have:

$$
xy + xy'z + x'yz = xy+xy'z+yz
$$
with $P=x, R=y, Q=z$ (refering to Bram28's notation), then it equals
$$
xy+xz+yz
$$
by applying the same rule with $P=y, R=x, Q=z$.

Answer (score 0):

$ xyz+xyz'+xy'z= xy(z+z')+xy'z= xy+xy'z= x(y+y'z) = x(y+y') (y+z) = x(y+z) = xy+xz $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).